# select query to select most updated records

Tags: sql

query to fetch latest updated records in my sql??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is vague and unanswerable as it currently stands.  Please include sample data and any query you have already attempted.

Comment: Are you in mssql? MySQL? tsql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

Above query will return recently updated 1 record.